# How to add column to a table with values of another column from a different table

Tags: mysql

The code `ALTER TABLE numbers_2 ADD COLUMN value_2 INT AS (value_1 / 2) VIRTUAL;` works when both columns are in the same table.

What needs to change when column "value_1" is in table "numbers_1" and column "value_2" is in table "numbers_2" ?

I tried the code `ALTER TABLE numbers_2 ADD COLUMN value_2 INT AS (numbers_1.value_1 / 2) VIRTUAL;` , but it's not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked table needs to know from which row the value should be taken. Somethink like the following should work:

```
ALTER TABLE numbers_2 ADD COLUMN value_2 INT AS 
    (SELECT numbers_1.value_1 / 2 FROM numbers_1 WHERE numbers_1.id = numbers_2.id) VIRTUAL
```

Comment: Hello. In fact, I need to create a new table (called numbers_2) with the values of column "value_1" from table "numbers_1" divided by 2. The new table will have the same number of rows as the table "numbers_1", But there is no column called "id" to be used in a "where clause".

Comment: then you can create the table from the other table with `CREATE TABLE numbers_2 SELECT numbers_1.value_1 / 2 AS value_2` like mentioned here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html